# Assembling a WebLogic Web Service Manually

Tags: web-services, weblogic12c

I implemented webservice as described in this [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webserv/dd.html) by simply creating "web-services.xml" with the following content (and offcourse i create the 'com.example.WorkFlowEntry' handler class ) :

```
<web-services>
<handler-chains>
   <handler-chain name="enterWorkflowChain">
       <handler class-name="com.example.WorkFlowEntry">
           <init-params>
               <init-param name="workflow-eng-jndi-name" 
                           value="workflow.entry" />
            </init-params>
       </handler>
   </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
<web-service targetNamespace="http://example.com" 
              name="myworkflow" uri="myWorkflowService">
    <operations xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
       <operation name="enterWorkflow" 
                  handler-chain="enterWorkflowChain"
                  invocation-style="one-way" />
    </operations>
</web-service>
```

My issue is that when i deploy the EAR file in weblogic 11g the '' webservice is deployed successfully and i can access the WSDL of the webservice. When i deploy the same EAR in weblogic 12c it got deployed successfully but the WSDL is not accessible i am getting 404!

Comment: Did you check that you ear is started in your 12c domain ? Use the admin console and go to the deployment option to check that.

Comment: Yes .. started and active with no Error or Warning.

Comment: Same for me. Everything seems ok, but getting 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Manually assembling weblogic web service is valid if you are using the
>   Webservice 8.1 environment. The last Weblogic version for which this
>   approach can be used is Weblogic 12.1.1, from Weblogic 12.1.2 release,
>   the 8.1 WebLogic Web services run time has been removed.

that means using the 'web-services.xml' to build your webservice is valid till weblogic 12.1.1 version. for the newer version you have to upgrade your webservice implementation as mentioned in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLUPG/upgrade_ws.htm#WLUPG334) which mainly go through (Upgrading a 10.x WebLogic Web Service (JAX-WS or JAX-RPC) to 12.1.x). **But this solution may affect the current running clients**.

In my case i cannot ask the client to change their code. So my workaround for this case is to take the current WSDL and generate the webservice manually by **ant** as described in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13758/use_cases.htm#WSGET119) which is describes using wsdlc Ant task to generate the following artifacts:

- JWS service endpoint interface (SEI) that implements the Web service described 
  by the WSDL file.
- JWS implementation file that contains a partial (stubbed-out) implementation of 
  the generated JWS SEI. This file must be customized by the developer.
- JAXB data binding artifacts.
- Optional Javadocs for the generated JWS SEI.